# how to make certain editable field as non editable in alv report for custom field

Tags: report, abap, alv

I have used this code for disable of shipped status but in output it still shows as editable for shipped status

[image]

I want exact solution to make particular field for status shipped as disabled.

```
  LOOP AT IT_FINAL INTO WA_FINAL.

    IF WA_FINAL-STATUS = 'PACKED'.

      ls_stylerow-fieldname = 'NOTE' .
      ls_stylerow-style = cl_gui_alv_grid=>mc_style_enabled.
      APPEND ls_stylerow  TO wa_FINAL-field_style.
      MODIFY IT_FINAL FROM wa_FINAL TRANSPORTING  field_style.

    elseif wa_FINAL-STATUS = 'SHIPPED'.
      ls_stylerow-fieldname = 'NOTE' .
      ls_stylerow-style = cl_gui_alv_grid=>mc_style_disabled.
      APPEND ls_stylerow  TO wa_FINAL-field_style.
      MODIFY it_FINAL FROM wa_FINAL TRANSPORTING field_style.

    ENDIF.
```

Comment: Need minimal reproducible code to give any meaningful answers. Probably you are forgetting the method call  `CALL METHOD grid1->set_ready_for_input 
                     EXPORTING i_ready_for_input = 1.`    Refer to SAP standard program BCALV_EDIT_02 and see what you are missing.

Comment: Why are you using `LOOP INTO` in the first place instead of `LOOP ASSIGNING`? Would save you the `MODIFY` and erasing the possibility of modifying the wrong row